# ksh difference between $ and ${}

Tags: shell, ksh

Can someone explain to me what is the difference, in Korn shell, between:

```
ANOTHER_VAR=${SOME_VAR}
```

and

```
ANOTHER_VAR=$SOME_VAR
```

I came across these types of declaration and can't see what the difference is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One has two brace characters around the name and the other doesn't; otherwise, in this context, there is no difference.

However, if you had:

```
ONE_VAR="$TWO_VAR_$THREE_VAR"
UNO_VAR="${TWO_VAR}_${THREE_VAR}"
```

then the values in `$ONE_VAR` and `$UNO_VAR` will be different unless both `$TWO_VAR` and `$TWO_VAR_` exist and `$TWO_VAR_` holds the value that is stored in `$TWO_VAR` plus a trailing underscore (where `$TWO_VAR` could be an empty string, or undefined, as long as `$TWO_VAR_` holds just an underscore).

<sup>Thanks to [William Pursell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/140750/william-pursell) for [pointing out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27364826/ksh-difference-between-and/27364894?noredirect=1#comment43181810_27364894) a minor inaccuracy in the previous version.</sup>

There are many contexts where you must use the braces, such as:

```
UNE_VAR=${YET_ANOTHER_VAR:-"default setting"}
```

Comment: nit: ONE_VAR and UNO_VAR are the same only if `$TWO_VAR` is the same as `$TWO_VAR_` with a trailing underscore removed.  If they are the same, the UNO_VAR gets an extra underscore.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: Oh, yes...consider the nit picked.